# Cannot change value with a timer

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm reporting issues when I try to change a variable value with a timer.

Actually I'm using the following code to perform that:

```
local counter = math.random(100, 350)
local function changeCounterValue()
    counter = math.random(130, 170)
end
tmr = timer.performWithDelay(1500, changeCounterValue, 0)
```

but it just doesn't work?

Comment: what has this got to do with android?

Comment: Corona targets both Android and iOS, but this is pretty clearly a Corona/Lua question that's independent of the target platform.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm developing my app using CORONA SDK

Comment: The code you given here is correct, and will update the value of counter in every 1500 ms. You are printing the updated value inside the function, right..? Otherwise you may not able to get the updated value...

Comment: No need to put "Solved" in question title. Read about [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score -1):

When you use timer, you are changing scope of variables. So with your timer, you are creating another counter variable, not updating the value. What you should do is this:

test.lua:

```
counter = math.random(100, 350)

local function changeCounterValue()
    test.counter = math.random(130, 170)
end

tmr = timer.performWithDelay(1500, changeCounterValue, 0)
```